# PHP page not hiding a DIV using visibility:none or display:none

Tags: php, javascript, css, html, hidden

A PHP page I am working on can be loaded in several states, in the default state I need one DIV layer to be visible and another one to not be visible - and vice versa.
The script has javascript backup to do the same things, BUT I need the css to work for persons viewing the page with javascript disabled.

The code for the first DIV works fine:

```
<pre><</pre>div name="MoreDiv" ID="MoreDiv" style="position: absolute;top: 10px; left: 15px;  width: 95%; font-size:1.3em; 
<?php
if(isset($_GET['page']))
{
$ipi = getenv("REMOTE_ADDR");
$u = getenv ("HTTP_REFERER");
$httpagenti = getenv ("HTTP_USER_AGENT");

$page = $_GET['page'];
switch($page)
{
case 404:
{echo '';
break;}

default:
{ ?>

<?php }

break;}
} 
else { //
?>visibility:none; display:none;<?php }
?>">
```

... So you'd think that for the other DIV, that needs to be hidden when the ?page variable is set in the URL, putting the "visibility:none; display:none;" attributes inside the default for the php output would work - a bit like this:

```
div name="PhotoText" ID="PhotoText" style="position: absolute;top: 15px; left: 15px; width: 400px; font-size:1.3em; background: rgb(0, 0, 0); background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7); padding:10px; -webkit-border-radius: 10px;  -moz-border-radius: 10px; border-radius: 10px; -khtml-border-radius: 10px; <?php
if(isset($_GET['page']))
{$page = $_GET['page'];
switch($page)
{
case "test":
{?>
visibility:none; display:none;

<?php
break;}

default:
{ ?>
visibility:none; display:none;

<?php }

break;}
}   

else { //
?><?php }
?>">
```

And yet for some strange and really bizarre reason the DIV STILL SHOWS!... and it stays visible until the page has fully loaded and the javascript within the "body onload" tag kicks in to hide it. I cannot use the PHP to keep the DIV layer blank for the default URL variable, as there are javascript links which require it to be there in order to load content.... so I need a non-JS way of hiding this layer, but in such a way that JS can be used to make it visible again!!

Comment: Code formatting and readability is a critical and overlooked skill by many beginning to intermediate programmers/developers. The way you're formatted that is going to be highly prone to errors since, more or less, you can't readily look at it and figure out what the flow or intent is or where exactly you are. Please review [PHP: The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/), at least the [Code Style Guide](http://www.phptherightway.com/#code_style_guide) (and the [PSR](http://www.php-fig.org/faq/) style recommendations). You really have to pay attention to it to be successful. `:)`

Comment: Also, it's `visibility: hidden;` and `display: none;`, and `visibility` and `block` do not do the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

There's really several ways of accomplishing this. First of all, *never*, **ever**, interpolate an `if` and a `switch` type of logic *within an attribute's value* as you have it in your question. Recipe, meet disaster.

On the [`visibility`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/visibility) vs [`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/display) question, this QA actually depicts it pretty well:

http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/f/blfaqhidden.htm

More or less, `visibility` still maintains it's "space" in the flow of the document, whereas `display` affects it's flow (including removing it entirely). Easy to mix up, totally different concepts.

Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TGaa3/embedded/result/1), and the [source markup](http://jsfiddle.net/TGaa3/1) and CSS.

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="novisibility" class="test">
        <p>Visiblity<br>Will you see me?<br>Will I still be "there"?</p>
    </div>
    <div id="nodisplay" class="test">
        <p>Block<br>Will you see me?<br>Will I disappear?</p>
    </div>
    <p id="buttons">
        <button type="button" id="visibility">Toggle Visibility</button>
        <button type="button" id="display">Toggle Display</button>
    </p>
</div>

#wrapper.hide #nodisplay {
    display: none;
}
#wrapper.invisible #novisibility {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

The Javascript is toggling the `.hide` and `.novisibility` classes on the `#wrapper`.

I would suggest a template pattern, where you separate the logic from the markup/display layer. For instance:

**page.php**

```
<?php

// ... other stuff

if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
    $page = $_GET['page'];

    switch($page) {
        case "test":
           $cls = " NoDisplay";
        break;
        default:
           $cls = " Highlight";
        break;
    }
}

// ... other stuff

?>
```

Where you hae this defined in your CSS (not in a `style` attribute if you can help it):

**/assets/css/site.css**

```
.PhototextContent.NoDisplay {
    display: none;
}
.PhototextContent.Highlight {
    background: yellow;
    display: block;
}
```

**docPagePhotoInline.tpl**

```
<!-- Other photo stuff, I presume. -->
<div id="PhotoText" class="PhotoTextContent<?php echo $cls; ?>">Your content</div>
```

I also wonder if you're reusing that `id` value; you [should (can) only have one unique `id` per page](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#id-selectors). If you need something to cover several elements, use `class` names to group elements by *class*. Also note, `name` in `div`s are still valid I think, but rarely used by anyone. Use `id` to uniquely identify an element.

So which do you think is easier to read? I don't think it's hard to see what I'm up to here, but it takes a double look with what you've got, followed by some head-scratching. Your code should be expressive of intent; code that feels well-tended and that feels right when you look at it isn't always great code, but inelegant, whiplash formatting is often an indicator the code could be problematic. Think of it like a garden; a well tended and organized garden is much more appealing than one that's, well, not.

So I'd implement at least a basic templating approach. There's several decent tutorials out there, like [this one](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/17/getting-started-with-php-templating/). I'd like to try out [Mustache for PHP](https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php) soon, but there's others like [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/), [Flexy](http://pear.php.net/package/HTML_Template_Flexy/redirected), [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/), and [Dwoo](http://dwoo.org/). Keep in mind PHP itself may be used as a templating system, and most template system compile the templates into PHP or bytecode. You just need to be careful to separate the logic from the view or display layer.

You should pair them with an approach, though, so I'd suggest a framework using the [MVC pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller). There's a lot out there, like [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/overview/mvc.html), [TinyMVC](http://www.tinymvc.com/), [Kohana](http://kohanaframework.org/), [Cake](http://cakephp.org/), etc. This looks reasonable:

http://phpsavant.com/

Try not to hang out there on your own too much, though.

Comment: Having a good look through, it seems as though the php script is not "getting" what $page is set at, permanently retracting to the ELSE output... despite the exact same 'get' code being used further up the page to include a php file if $page is set. bizarre.

Comment: Now fixed php issue with this: <?php if (stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'?page=') !== false) {echo 'visibility:none; display:none;';} ?> ... and now the layer hides itself properly. All is well.